# Java access misunderstanding

Tags: java

Why does the following code compile fine?

```
public class MyStack {

    private static MyStack myStack ;
    private Stack<MyObject> stackOfMyObjects;

    private MyStack() {
        stackOfMyObjects = new Stack<MyObject>() ;
    }

    public static void pushToStack(MyObject myObject, MyStack myStack2) {
        myStack2.stackOfMyObjects.push(myObject) ;
    }

}
```

Here, in the **pushToStack** method, how can the **stackOfMyObjects** member of **myStack2**, event though **stackOfMyObjects** has been defined private?

Comment: Are you asking why the function in a class can access the private members of instances of that class? If not, who could?

Comment: Private to the class, not to the object. So if you need to implement `int compareTo(T rhs)` you can access right-hand-side fields too.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I still don't get it. You still seem to be asking "why can the member functions of a class access the private members of instances of that class?" And the answer is, "If they couldn't, who or what could?" The whole point of private member variables is for member functions of the class to freely access them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Here, in the pushToStack method, how can stackOfMyObjects be accessed from myStack2, event though stackOfMyObjects has been defined private?

Because it's still a `MyStack`. Access control in Java is about where the code appears, not whether it's accessing a "different" object.

Basically, all code within `MyStack` is trusted to use private members declared within `MyStack`.

See [section 6.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) for more details. Specifically, in section 6.6.1:

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Here, the access *does* occur within the body of the top level class (`MyStack`) that encloses the declaration of the `stackOfMyObjects` variable, so access is permitted.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is of the same Class.

Private is in class scope, not object scope, and so when inside a Class, you can access all private/protected members of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that **myStack2** is of Type **MyStack**.
**stackOfMyObjects** is defined private yes, but its still in the same **Class** MyStack. It's a global defined variable, which can be accessed from all Objects, which have been created from this class..